# Laravel/Passport set auth for methods

Tags: php, laravel

I installed `Laravel` and `Passport` to make a REST API, api data works fine, I installed passport and set configuration successfully but there is a problem, I don't how to set passport auth for my routes:

```
Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostController@show');
Route::post('posts', 'PostController@store');
Route::put('posts/{post}', 'PostController@update');
Route::delete('posts/{post}', 'PostController@delete');
```

I tried:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
    Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostController@show');
});
```

> 404 not found

And also:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group( function () {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController@index');
});
```

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route
>   [login] not defined.

So how can I use passport on my routes?

**POSTMAN:**

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
>   [login] not defined. in file
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php
>   on line 412

Comment: The error suggests it's trying to resolve the Route by route name which would mean that in your Laravel App you are calling `route('login')` somewhere but it has not been defined.

Comment: The fact that it tries to redirect you to login, i believe that you have enabled the web auth guard, which if you are not authorized will redirect you to the login page